# Extracting URL from inside docx tables

Tags: python, xml, hyperlink, docx

I'm pretty much stuck right now.

I wrote a parser in python3 using the `python-docx` library to extract all tables found in an existing .docx and store it in a python datastructure.

So far so good. Works as it should.

Now I have the problem that there are hyperlinks in these tables which I definitely need! Due to the structure (xml underneath) the docx library doesn't catch these. Neither the url nor the display text provided. I found many people having similar concerns about this, but most didn't seem to have 'just that' dilemma.

I thought about unpacking the .docx and scan the *_ref* document for the corresponding 'rid' and fill the actual data I have with the links found in the *_ref* xml.

Either way it seems seriously weary to do it that way, so I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do it or if somebody got good advise how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the links by parsing xml of docx file. 
You can extract all text from the document by using `document.element.getiterator()`

Iterate all the tags of xml and extract its text. You will get all the missing data which python-docx failed to extract.